# Connect by prior for DB2

Tags: database, oracle, db2

I have a problem with hierarchical queries, the following query is working in Oracle, but not in DB2

It will retrieve the destination which can be possible if we start our journey from Chicago..

```
SELECT   origin, departure, arrival
FROM  schema001."FLIGHTS"
START WITH departure = 'Chicago'
CONNECT BY PRIOR arrival = departure;
```

Can any one help me, how can we write the query in DB2

Thanks In Advance
Rajesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive common table expresion.

Something like this:

```
with ftree (origin, departure, arrival) as (
   select origin, 
          departure, 
          arrival
   from flights
   where departure = 'Chicago'
   union all
   select c.origin,
          c.departure,
          c.arrival
   from flights c
      join ftree p on c.arrival = p.departure
)
select *
from ftree;
```

(Not tested, don't have a DB2 at hand right now)

Answer (score 1):

Cheers.... I got the solution, 
Working solution is ....

```
WITH rajesh(departure, arrival) AS 
(
select departure, arrival from ALERTS_TEST.flights where departure = 'Chicago'
    UNION ALL
select nplus1.departure, nplus1.arrival  from ALERTS_TEST.flights as nplus1, rajesh
    WHERE rajesh.arrival = nplus1.departure
) 
SELECT departure, arrival FROM rajesh;
```

I have checked the above query in db2 v9.7 and sqlserver 2005.
It's working fine...
Thanks for ur help a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which OS DB2 is running on.

DB2 for i running on IBM i OS 7.1 *does* have [hierarchical queries](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzhierquery.htm), but the syntax is just slightly different.

```
SELECT   origin, departure, arrival
  FROM  schema001.FLIGHTS
  START WITH departure = 'Chicago'
  CONNECT BY arrival = PRIOR departure;
```

Unfortunately, I don't believe this will work on DB2 for LUW or z/OS.  Perhaps in a future release.